# How to add new tables to list for MySQL replication?

Tags: mysql, replication

I am a beginner in MySQL replication and I would like to setup permanent replication only for some selected tables.

That is why I am thinking about filtering by this my.cnf command:

```
replicate-wild-do-table= mydb.%Replicate
```

It does it means that all tables I would like to replicate will have "Replicate" suffix. Is this good solution or is there something better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think of a few cons when using a suffix:

- Depending on the suffix you choose, you may end up with table names having that suffix but that you don't want to replicate
- If you decide to change the fact that a table is replicated or not, you have to change the table name, which means changing all the stuff depending on that table name (generally, source code).

Therefore, I suggest list in my.cnf all the tables requiring replication, using as many [`replicate-do-table`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-do-table) directives as necessary.

Comment: OK, sounds as right solution for me, but I need to update this list of tables for replication each week with new ones and it would need to restart mysql to load new parameters from my.cnf file. Is there solution for such updates without restart?

Comment: Why exactly do you need to update the table list? Isn't it possible to replicate all tables which need, at some moment, to be replicated?

Comment: My web provide charts from social networks. I have one server which works as an indexer (master) and the second web server for users access. Sometimes I extend statistics with a new social networks. So that is why I need to update the list in my.cnf. 

It is needless to replicate all tables from master to slave, because on indexer side is a lot of tables which are not useful for frontend.

Comment: Would it be possible to store all the "stats" in a set of tables (for all social networks), using a foreign key to a single "social_network" table? This way, you would have to store only the necessary data into that (replicated) set of tables, thus changing the list of replicated tables shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Hmm, it is probably not possible, because each social network have another data structure. So it seems that the best is use replicate_do_table directive and restart mysql for update. OK, thanks!

Comment: You have the option to create an "adapter" per social network, allowing to gather stats data into the same data structure, before the replication step (since I guess that you will have to do such a "format conversion" somewhere in the process). Anyway, thanks for accepting my answer & good luck :)